# Different locations of file downloads

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am using webdriver.io for my end-to-end testing. I want to check if proper files are being downloaded.

My problem is with the file download location. I want to use separate downloads directory for each test browser instance (hence for each test file), because I want to have fresh directory under test.

I tried to set (in wdio.conf.js):

```
chromeOptions.prefs['download.default_directory'] = path.join(__dirname, "/downloads/", browserName, process.pid.toString());
```

using PID of the process, but it does not work. But the process.pid is the same for all tests. So how can I accomplished that? How to set different download directory (for Chrome browser) for each test browser instance and then grab that directory path in the test itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp as it will be different for all tests.

```
chromeOptions.prefs['download.default_directory'] = 
    path.join(__dirname, "/downloads/", browserName, new Date().getTime());
```